# How to set a javascript code value for an asp variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, var, response.write

How to set a javascript code value for an asp variable? 
In the following code **title: '<%=Zaman%>',** part **<%if act="buhafta" then%>** gives an empty result. What I have to do to make sure there is no empty result.

```
<script>
      function getWeekNumber(d) {
        // Copy date so don't modify original
        d = new Date(+d);
        d.setHours(0,0,0,0);
        // Set to nearest Thursday: current date + 4 - current day number
        // Make Sunday's day number 7
        d.setDate(d.getDate() + 4 - (d.getDay()||7));
        // Get first day of year
        var yearStart = new Date(d.getFullYear(),0,1);
        // Calculate full weeks to nearest Thursday
        var weekNo = Math.ceil(( ( (d - yearStart) / 86400000) + 1)/7);
        // Return array of year and week number
        return [d.getFullYear(), weekNo];
    }
    var result = getWeekNumber(new Date());
</script>
<%Dim Zaman
if act="bugun" then%>
<%Zaman=date()%>
<%end if%>
<%if act="dun" then%>
<%Zaman=date()-1%>
<%end if%>
<%if act="" OR act="buay" then%>
<%Zaman=(monthname(month(date)) & (" / ") & (year(date)))%>
<%end if%>
<%if act="oncekiay" and NOT operatorGor.eof then%>
<%Zaman=(monthname(month(operatorGor(4)))& (" / ") &(year(date)))%>
<%end if%>
<%if act="buhafta" then%>
<%Zaman=Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">document.write(result[0] + '- ' + result[1] +'. hafta');</script>") %>
<%end if%>
<%if act="gecenhafta" then%>
<%Zaman=Response.Write("<script type=""text/javascript"">document.write(result[0] + '- ' + (result[1]-1) +'. hafta');</script>") %>
<%end if%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnnotations);
function drawAnnotations() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Operatörler', 'Operator Performansları', {type: 'string', role: 'annotation'}],
            <%do while not operatorGor.eof%>
                    ['<%=operatorGor(0)%> (<%=operatorGor(2)%> Saatte, <%=operatorGor(4)%> Farklı Tipte, <%=operatorGor(3)%> Parça)' , <%=operatorGor(1)%>, '%' + <%=operatorGor(1)%>],
            <%operatorGor.MoveNext:loop%>
        ]);
        var options = {
        title: '<%=Zaman%>',
        chartArea: {width: '30%'},
        annotations: {
          alwaysOutside: true,
          textStyle: {
            fontSize: 10,
            auraColor: 'none',
            color: '#555'
          },
          boxStyle: {
            stroke: '#ccc',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            gradient: {
              color1: '#f3e5f5',
              color2: '#f3e5f5',
              x1: '0%', y1: '0%',
              x2: '100%', y2: '100%'
            }
          }
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Rework-Setup süreleri dahil değildir.',
          minValue: 0,
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Toplam Operatör Sayısı:<%=CInt(opsay(0))-1%>'
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>


<div style="width: 90%; border:2px solid #000; padding:5px; background-color:#fff; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 700px; font-size:10px"></div>
</div>
```